# undefined method `devise_for' in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, devise, undefined

After I install devise and create a user model. I `rake db:migrate` and then I `rake routes`.  I then get a error with "undefined method `devise_for' for  #".  What could be causing this error?

Comment: Have you added devise to your Gemfile? Can you check if `devise` is present in your Gemfile.lock too?

Comment: my gem file says gem 'devise', :git => 'git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git'

Comment: Based on the steps you mentioned, you will get this error if you don't have a `devise.rb` under `config/initializers`

Answer (score 281):

Remember to restart your rails server after installing and configuring devise.

Comment: When in doubt, restart the server.

Comment: Also comment out `devise_for :installs` in `routes.rb`

Comment: I wish the Rails server could watch files and auto-reload. Wasteful, yes, but it'd be damn convenient during development!

Answer (score 8):

If you have the Devise gem specified in the Gemfile, just make sure you have the following in your routes.rb file:

```
 devise_for :users
```

Also, here's a trick to make sure Devise is mapped properly, run: rails c, (the Rails app console) in your app's folder and then the following command line:

```
 Devise.mappings.keys
```

You should see:

```
=> [:user]
```

Cheers!

Comment: Hi Florin, thanks for your answer. I have "devise_for :users" line on my routes file, however when I run Devise.mappings.keys I got an error. How should I fix this?

Comment: Hi there - care to specify the error, unless you already found the solution?!

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I would recommend following these two Railscasts ([Episode 209](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise) and [Episode 210](http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise)). The first is a simple and very easy walkthrough for installing Devise and the second is about customizing it to fit your application.

I've watched both episodes and they drastically helped me with Devise, particularly with the customization.

Your best bet is to start from scratch - you'll learn a heck of a lot and have Devise fully installed and functional.

Hope this helps! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do a `bundle install`