# Ruby on Rails - Heroku application error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm doing the OneMonthRails program. New to Ruby on Rails, relatively new to coding. Did some research on this problem and I'm under the impression that it's a problem with the root, but I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the exact error:

> Application Error
>
> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
>   served. Please try again in a few moments.
>
> If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

This was a result of myself trying to fix this error:

> The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.

Here's my Heroku log:

```
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608007+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608006+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608010+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608014+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608018+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608022+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608026+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608023+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `require'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608030+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608033+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608040+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608037+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608045+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608042+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608053+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608049+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608057+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608052+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608075+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608060+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608063+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608068+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608071+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608067+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608079+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608086+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608078+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.634350+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-08-07T14:22:13.608083+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-08-07T14:22:13.634360+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-08-07T14:22:13.634355+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.3 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:13299
2015-08-07T14:22:13.634358+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-08-07T14:22:13.634357+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-08-07T14:22:05.944573+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2015-08-07T14:22:14.503409+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-08-07T14:22:14.516441+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-07T14:22:14.517665+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-08-07T14:22:17.517246+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 50913 -e production`
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237482+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `instance_exec'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237458+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `devise_for' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007fe2229afba8> (NoMethodError)
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237484+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `eval_block'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237487+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237488+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237486+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:412:in `draw'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237490+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237491+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237493+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237497+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237499+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237500+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237496+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237501+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237505+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237506+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237507+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237511+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237512+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237516+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237519+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237520+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237524+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237527+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237531+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237533+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237536+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237540+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237541+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237544+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237548+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237553+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `require'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237551+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237556+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237560+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237563+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237567+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237569+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237573+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237578+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237581+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237584+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237586+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237589+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237596+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237593+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237601+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237600+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237604+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237608+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237611+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237615+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237618+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.237620+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-08-07T14:22:21.262107+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-08-07T14:22:21.262113+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.3 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:50913
2015-08-07T14:22:21.262115+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-08-07T14:22:21.262116+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-08-07T14:22:21.262117+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-08-07T14:22:22.013448+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-08-07T14:22:22.409064+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=quiet-ridge-3064.herokuapp.com request_id=7632327c-58a1-4cf8-b828-b1303b245e11 fwd="74.98.213.219" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-07T14:22:22.042639+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-07T14:35:39.826645+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=quiet-ridge-3064.herokuapp.com request_id=f9299dc6-a798-4a8c-ac76-0d470c819ed3 fwd="74.98.213.219" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I've tried the following:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate

heroku db:reset

config.assets.compile = true
```

Here's my routes.db:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

devise_for :users
get 'welcome/index'
get 'welcome/about'
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'topics#index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

After I run `heroku run rake routes`

```
Running `rake routes` attached to terminal... up, run.1471
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `devise_for' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007f9fa1df78f0>
/app/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `eval_block'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:412:in `draw'
/app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
Tasks: TOP => routes => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
gem 'devise'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end
group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

I probably did something stupid or missed something that I shouldn't have.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `undefined method `devise_for' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007fe2229afba8>` is devise gem installed properly show your `Gemfile`

Comment: Hi Rajarshi, thank you for the quick response!

'I ran rails generate devise:install'

Now I'm getting a different error when I go to localhost   
  
" Routes match in priority from top to bottom  
  
You don't have any routes defined!

    Please add some routes in config/routes.rb.
    For more information about routes, please see the Rails guide Rails Routing from the Outside In."  
  
I added my routes.db folder to the original question. I have noticed mine looks entirely different than the ones posted on similar questions.

Comment: yes as devise install commmand automatically update routes.rb with `devise_for :users`

Comment: Post what returns when you run heroku run rake routes

Comment: Posted an edit with the results from the heroku run rake routes

Comment: Perhaps try restarting your rails server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810941/undefined-method-devise-for-in-rails

Comment: Getting NameError when trying to start server. Will not start. "uninitialized constant User (NameError)"

Comment: Edited to add gemfile. Thanks for the help everyone.